# highcharts - windrose stackLabel doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts 4.15 and I would like to display stack label for my wind rose chart, but it doen't work as I expected.
Here an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulson/xdvaecff/

```
yAxis: {
    stackLabels: {
        enabled: true
    }
}
```

I would like to have them near the end of each 'petal', but they appear in the left bottom corner.
Is there any fix or workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in a polar chart stack labels are forgotten at all (bug reported [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5826)).

As a workaround, you can use data labels which are positioned correctly.
Enabling data labels for the most upper series and returning the stack's total value in the formatter callback do the work.

```
series: [{
   ...
}, {
   ...
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function () {
            return this.total;
        }
    }
}]
```

In your case, you load data from csv and reverse stacking is disabled, so you can enable dataLabels for the last series in the complete callback:

```
        complete: function (options) {
            options.series[options.series.length - 1].dataLabels = {
              enabled: true,
              formatter: function () {
               return this.total;
              }
          }
        }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xdvaecff/1/

Comment: thanks. That worked! The only thing - data labels will dissapear if you hide this series. So I added another seria with no data and `showInLegend: false` and add datalabels to it.
Next step is to recalculate total when some series will be hide/shown

Comment: I did not think about hiding the series, but your solution does solve this problem.